# jest and babel config as ECMAScript module

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs

i get the following error when running `jest`

> You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.

but `"type": "module"` is set in `package.json` and `babel.config.js` looks as follows

```js
// babel.config.js
const config = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    ['@babel/preset-react', {runtime: "automatic"}]
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ],
};

export default config;
```

everything works when i rename `babel.config.js` to `babel.config.cjs` and change it to

```js
// babel.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    ['@babel/preset-react', {runtime: "automatic"}]
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ],
};
```

```js
// jest.config.js
const config = {};
export default config;
```

but i do not want to convert babel `babel.config.js` to commonjs or to json.
what am i doing wrong? how can i resolve the error?

Comment: please share your  Jest config file.

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury added the jest.config.js as you requested

Comment: This issue arises again. I'd like to dig into this. Probably requires some changes to `babel-jest` or `babel-preset-jest` and their usage of `require.resolve` That or `babel` needs some changes. `jest` and `react` are so hesitant to adopt an ESM-first approach, however, I think it's time they catch up.